# Having issue with MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

My function gets `$status` (0-error, 1-success), `$err_id` (id of error message in db) and `$field` (name of input field) variable and fetches error message from db, with given vars.

Tried `die()` in every step to detect where error occuring, also placed `die($status.$err_id.$field);` right after function `err`.  No success.

Debuged with netbeans. Marked the line in which debug stops in function

**$msg is always null**. Can't fetch it from db. There is no error in php error log. May be my code has mistake? Please take a look.

```
function err($status, $err_id = 0, $field = 0)
{
        global $db;
        if ($status == 0) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT msg FROM err_msgs WHERE field = ? AND id= ?") or die(htmlspecialchars($db->error));
                $stmt->bind_param("si", $field, $err_id) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                $stmt->execute() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                $stmt->bind_result($msg) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));

                >>debug stops here>> $stmt->fetch() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));

                response('error', $msg);
                $stmt->close();
                die();

        } else {
                response('success', 'Success!');

        }

}
```

Comment: Check the apache error log? Could be something killing php before it gets a chance to log anything itself.

Comment: sorry, the apache error log is about all I could think of. without any kind of error messages, it's pretty much impossible to diagnose.

Comment: there is no error IN PHP error log. Don't you see any mistake in my function?

Comment: apache's error log can be seperate from the php one. the code looks fine, so probably something else.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code.  It's peculiar that you're defaulting `$field` to 0 in the function.  I assume that you're passing in a `$field` and `$err_id` that exist in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to fetch after binding result

```
$stmt->fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

try switching these two lines:

```
$stmt->execute() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); 
$stmt->bind_result($msg) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
```

to

```
$stmt->bind_result($msg) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); 
$stmt->execute() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
```

Comment: "Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch()."  See docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: I did some testing on my site's forum, works both ways, with bind_result before and after the execute. I could swear I remember having to switch it from after to before in order to make it work...